# Why "mobile-inbox.org" filename cannot be changed?

Tags: org-mode, variables, mobileorg

I have

```
 (setq org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "~/org/m-Inbox.org")
```

in my `.emacs` (also set the var manually to the same effect), and still when doing `(org-mobile-pull)` emacs stores new entries in the file named `mobile-inbox.org` instead of `m-Inbox.org`

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching was the culprit!

Cleaning DB on the MobileOrg solved the issue of changed `mobile-inbox`

Comment: Please go ahead and accept your own answer so we can mark this question as completed.